# How to make a web part configurable?

Tags: web-part, development

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using publishing portal template.

I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I want to develop a WebPart and make some settings configurable (just like we can configure parameter for a console application in app.config) -- i.e. authorized people could set parameters of WebPart in Edit Page (from browser based UI interface), then select -> Modify WebPart properties, or edit parameter in SharePoint Designer.

Such parameter is application specific custom parameters.

Any solutions and referenced samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties should be built into just about any how to or sample project.

```
    [WebBrowsable(true), Personalizable(true)]
    public string DefaultText
    {
        get { return defaultText; }
        set { defaultText = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Are there a complete sample?

Comment: Cool, question answered!

Answer (score 4):

last year I wrote a series on Web Part properties, might be worth a look:

- [Web Part Properties - Part 1 - Introduction](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-1-introduction.aspx)
- [Web Part Properties - Part 2 - Editor Parts](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-2-Editor-Parts.aspx)
- [Web Part Properties - Part 6 - Complex Properties](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-6-Complex-Properties.aspx)

/WW

Comment: Nice series of articles there Wictor! :-)

Comment: Thnx mate! Trying to get them even better in the upcoming book!

Comment: Sounds awesome. Any details on that book yet?

Comment: Yea sure, check my blog.